# Applying vectorized subsetting across multiple columns in R

Tags: r, vectorization, subset, logical-operators, generalization

I try to find a straight-forward way to vectorize/generalize the subsetting of a data.frame. Let's assume I have a data.frame:

```
df <- data.frame(A = 1:5, B = 10 * 1:5, C = 100 * 1:5)
```

Every column has its own condition and the goal is subset the df so that only those rows remain where the condition is met for at least one column. I now want to find a vectorized subset mechanism that generalizes

```
df <- subset(df, df[,1]<2 | df[,2]< 30 | df[,3]<100)
```

so I could formulate it somewhat like this

```
crit <- c(2,30,100)
df <- subset(df, df$header < crit[1:3])
```

and down the road I want to get to.

```
df <- subset(df, df$header < crit[1:n])
```

I know a multi-step loop workaround, but there must be another way. I am grateful for any help.

Comment: Side note: `df <- data.frame(A = 1:5, B = 10 * 1:5, C = 100 * 1:5)` is easier than using 5 lines to create your data frame ;-)

Comment: `df[rowSums(mapply(\`<\`, df, crit)) > 0, ]` maybe?

Comment: thank you so much, I was so far down the subset rabbit hole I forgot about mapply!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given:

```
x <- c(1:5)
y <- c(10,20,30,40,50)
z <- c(100,200,300,400,500)

# df is a base function
mydf <- data.frame(A = x, B = y, C = z)

crit <- c(2,30,100)
```

Then this will let you see which values in the column are less than the crit value:

```
> sweep(mydf, 2, crit, "<")
         A     B     C
[1,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
[2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

And this will give you the rows that meet any of the criteria:

```
> subset(mydf, rowSums(sweep(mydf, 2, crit, "<")) > 0)

  A  B   C
1 1 10 100
2 2 20 200
```

Comment: works too, the mapply solution by rawr is a little faster, at least on my machine

Answer (score 1):

This should also work

```
> df[apply(df, 1, function(x){any(x < crit)}), ]
  A  B   C
1 1 10 100
2 2 20 200
```